# Save DOM in offline web archive(mht format) using ie6

Tags: dom, internet-explorer-6, save, offline, mhtml

I need to save the DOM in a offline web archive(mht format) using ie6. I need to make offline updates to the web archive and then save them back to the disk. However the "save as..." functionality is not including the DOM updates, is there a way to do this? Or perhaps a workaround?

Cheers,
Sam

Answer (score 1):

Use [saveSnapshot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531423) and choose "Web Page, HTML Only" rather than "Web Archive":

```
<style>
  .snapshot_alpha {behavior:url(#default#savesnapshot);}
</style>
<!--...-->
<input class="snapshot_alpha" type="text" id="persist_alpha">
```